# hudson svnkit SSL

Tags: svn, hudson, hudson-plugins, svnkit

I am using Hudson CI server with a project (or job) that is hosted on Subversion. I am connecting to a Subversion server over SSL.

Everything was working fine, and Hudson can update from subversion, build and there was no problem.

And just today, Hudson stopped checking out big changes on subversion. When there are lots of changes, Hudson, will start update from SVN, and then it gives this error:

ERROR: Failed to update https://myserver:8443/svn/myproject/trunk

org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: bad record MAC

svn: REPORT request failed on '/svn/CTPN/!svn/vcc/default'
and in the error stack

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)

and it will try every 10 seconds, and goes forever. It happened on the same day on two Hudson servers we are using

It is working for small update, but when it is large update it gives this error

any feedback please?

Comment: Does the certifacate of the Subversion server changed?

Comment: Try to fetch the url of the repos via wget, then you are asked to accepted the certificate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved.
We moved to another server, and it worked fine.
the admin guy thinks that either there is network problem that is not consistent between the hudson server and svn, or there was a capacity issue.
The hudson server was full, but the error message was network one.
could it be that there is a bug in svn plugin that when there is a capacity issue, it generate network?
because it was erroring out on huge checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch the url of the repos via wget.

Comment: It is giving me error that the certificate is a development certificate and it is not signed. but that was the situation all the time.

Comment: You have to add this certificate to the approved list of certificates on you machine.